# Characteristic function of $\chi^2$ distribution with one degree of freedom

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, normal-distribution

Just for my own curiosity, I'm trying to derive the characteristic function of $X\sim\chi^2_1$, the $\chi^2$ distribution with 1 degree of freedom. According to wikipedia, it is
$$
E[e^{itX}]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2it}},\quad t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
To proceed, I can think of $X$ as $U^2$ where $U\sim N(0,1)$. Then
$$
E[e^{itX}]=E[e^{itU^2}]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{itu^2}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-u^2/2}du=2\int_0^{+\infty}e^{itu^2}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-u^2/2}du.
$$
Let's make the substitution $y=u^2$ so that $dy=2udu$ with $u=\sqrt{y}$ for $u\geq 0$. Then
$$
E[e^{itX}]=2\int_0^\infty e^{ity}e^{-y/2}\frac{dy}{2\sqrt{2\pi y}}=\int_0^\infty\cos(ty)e^{-y/2}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}+i\int_0^\infty\sin(ty)e^{-y/2}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}
$$
but I can't proceed any further. :(

I have seen a derivation [here](http://www.planetmathematics.com/CentralChiDistr.pdf) but there is a substitution step that involves $i$ so I'm not comfortable with using it.